# C programming : Grouping multiple strings and searching for it using an Unique key

Tags: c

Let's say for example you are entering the personal information of a student and you create a unique ID number for each student. What I'm having problems with is grouping those strings, and storing them together, so that it can be accessed through the ID.

I tried using memory allocation, however, it did not work out.

I'm quite new to C, so I'm not exactly sure on what to do.
Here is what I used :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct {
  int LogID;
  char firstname[20];
  char lastname[20];
  int mark;
  char *subjects[100];
} student;

int reg(void);

int main(void) {
  reg();
  return 0;
}

//Registration function
int reg(void) {
  int choice,shift,found,compare, nosub, y, sub, subcount;
  char studentname[20];
  FILE *fp;
  FILE *fp2;

  printf("Enter Student Details:\n\nStudent ID: ");
  scanf("%d",&student.LogID);
  printf("Name: ");
  scanf("%s",student.firstname);
  printf("Surname: ");
  scanf("%s",student.lastname);
  printf("How many subjects does the student take? ");
  scanf("%d", &nosub);

  //Opens a text file and prints the student's ID and firstname
  fp2=fopen("subjects.txt","a+");
  fprintf(fp2, "\n\n%d\t%s", student.LogID, student.firstname);

  int i = 1;
  size_t malloc_size = 100; //Allocating memory size to store subjects student is taking
  for(i = 0; i < nosub; i++) {
    student.subjects[i] = malloc(malloc_size * sizeof(char));
    printf("Please enter the subject :\n(1)Mathematics\n(2)English\n(3) Social Studies\n(4)Science\n");
    scanf("%d", &sub);

    switch (sub) {
    case (1) :
      printf("Mathematics\n");
      break;
    case (2) :
      printf("English\n");
      break;
    case (3) :
      printf("Social Studies\n");
      break;
    case (4) :
      printf("Science\n");
      break;
    }
  }
  for(i = 0; i < nosub; i++) { //Prints subjects to file, but it doesn't work...
    fprintf(fp2,"%s\n", student.subjects[i]);
  }
  fclose(fp2);
  free(student.subjects[i]);
  student.subjects[i] = NULL;

  fp=fopen("studentfile.txt","a+");
//Prints certain student Information into another file...


  fprintf(fp,"\n%d\t%s\t%s\t",student.LogID,student.firstname,
          student.lastname);
  fclose(fp);
  printf("Registration has been successful\n");

  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, to start with, you're not storing anything in the subjects array. You allocate 100 characters for each subject string, but you never assign a subject to it.

Comment: In addition, I don't see any code about searching.

Comment: Points for having taken the [tour], have your read [Ask] and [MCVE] yet? You basically need to actually ask a specific question and supply a relevant MCVE.

Comment: Flagging as off-topic for lack of specifics.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield, ...you did? As of a few moments ago, I was the only close vote (since we have a bunch of code that *isn't* actually focused on/related to/necessary for being the shortest possible thing that can demonstrate a specific problem or error, as required by the MCVE definition).

Answer (score 0):

There were a number of issues I noticed and I'll address some of them, starting with the struct which I recommend defining like this:

```
struct studentpack {
    int LogID;
    char firstname[20];
    char lastname[20];
    int mark;
    char *subjects[100];
};
```

And under your main function, you can define the student entry for filling.

```
struct studentpack student;
```

which will be used over and over again in your code, as you did in your example, for filling from the user input.

In the switch you really don't need any parenthesis around the case numbers.

In addition to the printf statement in each case, try something like this:

```
case 1:
    printf("%s\n", "Mathematics");
    sprintf(student.subjects + i, "%s", "Mathematics");
    break;
```

which will fill the subjects area that you memory allocated just prior.

Finally, for grouping together the ID's I would suggest starting with something like this:

```
#define MAXGROUP 1000

struct studentpack *group = calloc(MAXGROUP, sizeof(struct studentpack));

int studentno = 0;
```

And then after you print your subjects to the file (test that it is working first due to the sprintf change) you would assign to the group like this:

```
if (studentno < MAXGROUP) {
    memcpy(group+studentno, &student, sizeof(struct studentpack));
    studentno++;
}
```

The above will store away the student. Next you will probably want to iterate through the group variable, accessing group[0].LogID, group[1].LogID, etc. (all the way up to a maximum of 1000) just to confirm that all your data is there in memory.

For example you could write a function that steps through looking for a particular LogID and then calls a show or display function containing printf statements to see all the values on screen.

Answer (score 0):

you need an array of students

```
struct student{
    int LogID;
    char firstname[20];
    char lastname[20];
    int mark;
    char *subjects[100];
};



struct student students[100];
```

you now have space for 100 students. They are students[0], students[1],...students[99]

Now you can do

```
int studno = 0;
While(something)
{
  printf("\Enter Student Details:\n\nStudent ID: ");
        scanf("%d",&(students[studno].LogID));

....
  studno++;
}
```